# Gulp works with regular command but not with git bash

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm, git-bash

Over the last few days I have an an issue with gulp running in git bash. Ive tried and tried everything, but no luck. Here is my error: [image: my error]

If you notice there is a C:\c\ and i was told that its cygwin syntax. I've never even heard of that before. Npm has worked with every other package I have downloaded and now it just wont work at all. The strange thing is that the same person who told me that it was cygwin syntax told me to try it in the windows command prompt and strange enough, it worked.[image: gulpwindows]

How do I change the path so it doesnt have the c\ and its just C:\

This is the strangest thing I have seen so far, but any help at all would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Would http://dreamcloud.artark.ca/how-to-make-node-js-portable-on-windows-gitmsys/ help?